# how to execute insert, update and delete (sql server) query in swift

Tags: sql-server, swift

I'm trying to create an IOS application by Xcode (swift) for my business. I use https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient for my connection and I success.
I can connect and I can execute selection queries, getting successfully results. But I don't know how to execute insert, update and delete query in swift. 
For Example, 
for delete query (codes are below) there is no result, query could not executed.
for update query (codes are below) 'Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call' error has accured.
How do I accomplish this issue, please help me.

```
@IBAction func FbtnDeleteAct(_ sender: Any) {
        let username = FtxtUserOut.text
        let usersifre = FtxtPassOut.text
        let userstatu = FtxtStatuOut.text
        if (username == "" || username == nil || usersifre == "" || usersifre == nil || userstatu == "" || userstatu == nil){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Deneme", message: "Kullanıcı Adı, Şifre ve Statu Boş Olamaz..", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Tamam", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }else {
            deletequery = "Delete from Usertbl where Id=" + kulid
            client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
            client.delegate = self
            client.connect(strIP,username: strUName,password: strPass,database: strDBName){ success in
                if success {
                    self.client.execute(self.deletequery){
                        results in
                        for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                            for row in table {
                                for (columnName, value) in row {
                                    print("\(columnName) = \(value)")}}}
                    }
                }}
        }
    }

@IBAction func FbtnUpdateAct(_ sender: Any) {
        let username = FtxtUserOut.text
        let usersifre = FtxtPassOut.text
        let userstatu = FtxtStatuOut.text
        updatequery = "Update Usertbl set UserId='" + username! + "',Password='" + usersifre! + "' , UserStatus='" + userstatu! + "' where Id=" + kulid
        if (username == "" || username == nil || usersifre == "" || usersifre == nil || userstatu == "" || userstatu == nil){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Deneme", message: "Kullanıcı Adı, Şifre ve Statu Boş Olamaz..", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Tamam", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }else {
            client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
            client.delegate = self
            client.connect(strIP,username: strUName,password: strPass,database: strDBName){ success in
                if success {
                    self.client.execute(self.updatequery)
                }}

        }

    }
```

Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call
Insert ', completion: <#(([Any]?) -> Void)?#>'

Comment: Not sure how to call that objective-c api but have you tried to explicitly send nil as the completion parameter, `self.client.execute(self.deletequery, completion: nil)`

Comment: You also need to parameterize your queries. And you need to use a salted and hashed password instead of storing them in plain text.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I have tried 'self.client.execute(self.deletequery, completion: nil)', in that case , General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server 20018 15 error message was printed

Comment: how can I parameterize my queries dear Sean Lange? Could you please give me an example.

Comment: But that certainly looks like errors from the database which means your function worked in the sense that a query was sent.

Comment: I tried something like that to see whether the result of query is nil or not.
after  'self.client.execute(self.deletequery)' code, I added codes below:
{ success in  if (success != nil) {   print("Successful") }else { print("Failed")  } }
when I run, print Failed.

Comment: I found my mistake. but first of all, so thanks to Joakim Danielson for the correct advice that:  self.client.execute(self.deletequery, completion: nil) –
my query strings are also correct, failure cause is that: kulid (variable used in query) is nil, so execution of query returns nil. I added following code: 
kulid = FlblIdOut.text
so my problem was solved.